# Bypass auto wiring using services.yml symfony

Tags: php, symfony, php-7

I have a quick question regarding auto wiring on symfony.
I am currently migrating my symfony 2.8 app to symfony 5.4. I have my BaseManager class which is used by several manager of my application.
Several managers therefore use this class and pass it 2 arguments as parameters which are EntityManager and $class.

Of course, the $class variable is different for each manager and therefore cannot be managed by auto wiring.

So I have my managers that are declared as a service. However these declarations are not recognized by the auto wiring because I use an alias for these services. Is there a way to link my service alias to my manager without having to recreate several statements with the full name of the manager in the services.yml? this is a bit redundant, especially since I have about forty managers to transfer.

Thank you

This is my custom services.yml

```
# Employee Manager
WORD\EmployeeBundle\Service\EmployeeManager:
    arguments:
        - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
        - '%word.employee.model.employee.class%'
    public: true
    
# Employee Manager
word.employee.manager.employee:
    class: 'WORD\EmployeeBundle\Service\EmployeeManager'
    arguments:
        - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
        - '%word.employee.model.employee.class%'
    public: true
```

This is my custom baseManager who expect $em and $class

```
abstract class BaseManager{

protected $em;


protected $repository;


protected $class;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, string $class)
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->repository = $em->getRepository($class);

    $metadata = $em->getClassMetadata($class);
    $this->class = $metadata->name;
}
```

Comment: 1. As posted you are actually creating two distinct services, one with an id of `EmployeeManager::class` and one with an id of `word.employee.manager.employee` They are not `linked` in any meaningful sense and having two such services around could case issues.  Take a look at the `alias` section in the service container docs.

Comment: 2. You can tell autowire to skip classes by adding them to the exclude section in services.yaml.  You might need one line per class (depending on your naming convention) but that is better than needing multiple lines per class.

Comment: 3.  Why is the Employee class name being passed to the constructor?  Seems like the manager would know what class it is managing.  Maybe the parameter can be eliminated?  Or maybe you do have multiple types of employees but only one manager.

Comment: Hello @Cerad, thank you for your answers.  1. I'm doing a migration so I got the old services.yml files that contain ids. These IDs are used in other parts of the app so I can't delete them. Also the IDs can't be use with auto wiring. I have already looked at the documentation on the aliases but from what I understand, I would still have the declaration of these 2 services. This is what I want to avoid

Comment: 3. the BaseManager is used by several entities to gather common functions (employee, customer, etc.)
I don't want to change the logic of the application for the moment, I just want to focus on the migration which is already very time-consuming ^^

Comment: Well okay but once again the term [alias](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/alias_private.html#aliasing) has a very specific meaning for the Symfony service container.  Replacing your first definition with something like `WORD\EmployeeBundle\Service\EmployeeManager: '@word.employee.manager.employee'` should be all you need to take the next step.  And to be clear I am not suggesting changing your BaseManager.  I was suggesting tweaking your EmployeeManager class so it would pass the class name to it's constructor.

Comment: ok thanks you, the alias seems to be working fine. I thought that declaring the same service twice without differences was not a "good practice" even with the alias. Oh ok, I didn't quite understand. Yeah that was a good idea too